# Team Services deploy to Azure App

Tags: azure, build, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

For the first time, I am trying to create a build definition in Team Services (formerly VSO). I have setup a custom agent so I can run my Selenium tests. This works fine. I can now Build my solution and test my assemblies and run my Selenium tests.

Now I want to deploy my solution. And this is where I am stuck for two days. I just don't understand how all this works. Apparently, I need some zip-file, which I need to deploy on Azure. This is what I now use in my build step:

`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)"`

When I view the log of the build step, I can't find anything that says that a zip file is created.

So I think to first step to Azure deployment is to find out how to create a zip file. After that, I think I need to refer to that zipfile in my "Azure Web App Deployment" step. Am I right?

But first: how do I create the zipfile?

Answer (score 0):

The zip file is already created with the arguments you specified:

```
/p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
```

And with `/p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)"` arugment, the zip file is placed in the $(build.stagingDirectory) folder while $(build.stagingDirectory) is a environment variable which point to the build staging folder.

So, if you are using a hosted build agent, the zip file will be placed in:

```
C:\a\1\a
```

And if you are using your own build agent, the zip file will be placed in:

```
buildagentworkfolder\1(orothernumber)\a
```

By the way, if you are using "Azure Web App Deployment" task in the same definition with build and test, you can simply set "Web Deploy Package" to "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)***.zip".

Comment: Thanks, but that's the problem: no zipfile is created. If I search in Explorer to *.zip. I get no results. My `a` folder stays empty.

Comment: @Martijn Which project type are you building?

Comment: I have a solution with multiple projects. The one I want to deploy is a MVC project

Comment: @Martijn Did you see any logs like "2016-09-22T09:38:57.7510469Z   Package "xxx.zip" is successfully created as single file at the following location:
2016-09-22T09:38:57.7510469Z   file:///C:/a/1/a" in your build? Is it possible to share your build logs and build definitions?

Comment: My build log: https://jpst.it/NE8I and my build definition: https://justpaste.it/yl4x

Comment: @Martijn Is Web Deploy V3 installed on your build agent? And can you try a build with hosted build agent to see if it can generate the zip file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123933/discussion-between-martijn-and-eddie-msft).

Comment: @Martijn Add according to the logs, there are several projects are not selected for "Test | Any CPU" configuration, you also need to check if the project you'd like to build is selected for this configuration.

Comment: I have Web Deploy V3 installed and the project I want to deploy is checked (i.e. it has a checkbox in the Build column in configuration manager) in my Test - Any CPU configuration. When building using the hosted agent I see this for several projects:  `Package "x.zip" is successfully created as single file at the following location:`

Comment: But I don't see a zip for the (MVC) project I want to deploy

Comment: @Martijn Then what's the project included in the generated zip?

Comment: Here's a link with the build log using the Hosted Build Agent: https://jpst.it/NGdY The project I want to zip is called Deliverdd.Web

Comment: @Martijn I didn't see the "Deliverdd.Web" project is built from this log.

Comment: @Martijn Can you click the "Download all logs as zip" button to get the entire logs?

Comment: @Martijn The project is built and zip is created according to this log: Package "Deliverdd.Web.zip" is successfully created as single file at the following location:
2016-09-23T06:23:32.7091418Z   file:///C:/a/1/a

Comment: I've copied the text from the browser instead of looking in this log, sorry. But okay, the zip is created using the Hosted Build Agent, But why aren't those zipfiles created on my own agent with the same configurtion?

Comment: @Martijn Then it should be caused by the configuration of your own agent. Can you also download the entire logs for the build on your own agent and then share it?

Comment: here is the link which contains the log of my own agent: http://www.filedropper.com/logs126

Comment: @Martijn Can you remove the "/p:outputpath="C:\Visual Studio Online\Published" arguments and queue a new build and then share the logs? By the way, can you check if there is a build for Deliverdd.Web project  placed in C:\Visual Studio Online\Published folder?

Comment: Yes, I see the build dir, but in a subfolder: https://jpst.it/NGrF And here is the dump of the log files: http://www.filedropper.com/logs129

Comment: @Martijn It seems that "DeployOnBuild" is not triggered during the build. Is your VS installed completely with MSBuild target?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. I have installed VS 2015 Community Edition on my build agent

Comment: @Martijn Can you try run the build manually with these arguments on your own build agent?

Comment: When I execute the command `msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true` for one project, I cannot find a zip file. I've searched for it in the project dir, but there's no zipfile

Answer (score 0):

You can add another build task to archive files.

Once build is done you know where all the files are copied, put the source folder location in the 'Root folder (or files) to Archive' textbox and target location in the 'Archive File to create' textbox.

```
  $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

This will create a zip file in the staging folder which you can use in the release steps.